# Regex for password grading

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a regular expression grading the quality of the used password. The idea is that a password is considered mediocre if it contains ONLY 1 uppercase character OR atleast 6 uppercase characters. The password itself should be atleast 8 characters long.

Desired behavior:

Aaaaaaaa -> match

AAAAAAaa -> match

AAaaaaaa -> no match

I tried something like this:

`(?=.*[A-Z]{1,1}|(?=.*[A-Z]{6,})).{8,}`

Which doesn't do the trick because it also matches on AAaaaaaa. The problem is the first positive lookahead which allows 2-5 uppercase characters but i couldn't figure out how to avoid that.

Comment: Why shouldn't `AAaaaaaa` match? It has at least 1 uppercase letter.

Comment: `{1,1}` is kinda useless...

Comment: If there is one capital letter as condition, it will always succeed even if there a two or three or four capital letters

Comment: `AAaaaaaa` is considered a "better" password and therefore shouldn't match.

Comment: For so many questions, xkcd seems to have an appropriate cartoon : https://xkcd.com/936/ (correct horse battery staple)

Comment: 6 uppercase letters on end/at a stretch, or at any locations? In other words, https://regex101.com/r/tF1wZ7/3 or https://regex101.com/r/tF1wZ7/2?

Comment: What I use to grade password strength: lowercase it, put it thru MD5 and search on google. If the first page contains original password, reject it as a weak one. Simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should restrict the first lookahead to only require 1 uppercase letter in the *whole* string. Just define the full string pattern as *any non-uppercase letter(s) followed with 1 uppercase one, and then any number of non-uppercase letter characters are allowed*.

If you plan to require 6 uppercase letters at a row, use

```
/^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$|.*[A-Z]{6,}).{8,}$/
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tF1wZ7/6)

If these 6 uppercase letters can be scattered around the string, use

```
/^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$|(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){6,}).{8,}$/
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Where `(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){6,}` searches for at least 6 occurrences of 0+ non-uppercase letter characters followed with an uppercase letter. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tF1wZ7/7).

If you need to support Unicode, add `/u` modifier at the end of the regex, and replace `[A-Z]` with `\p{Lu}`, `[^A-Z]` with `\P{Lu}`.

Also, it is recommended to use `\A` instead of `^` and `\z` instead of `$` since it is password validation.

Another regex that is based on the logic suggested by [bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37564650/3832970):

```
^                           # String start
 (?=.{8,}$)                 # 8 or more characters other than a newline
 (?:
   [^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]* # a string with 1 uppercase letter only
    |                       # or...
   (?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){6}      # 6 occ. of 0+ chars other than uppercase letters followed with 1 uppercase letter
   .*                       # 0+ chars other than a newline
 )
$                           # string end
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL8iN1/3) and as 1 line:

```
/^(?=.{8,}$)(?:[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z][^A-Z\n]*|(?:[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z]){6}.*)$/
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL8iN1/2).

Comment: `^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$|([^A-Z]*[A-Z]){6}[^A-Z]*$).{8,}$`

Comment: @splash58: That is further pattern "technical" enhancement, and yes, there can be more of them.

Comment: @splash58 Please prove my regex matches `7A`. It does not. Nor `7 A`. See https://regex101.com/r/zF5yX9/1 and https://regex101.com/r/tB9xO5/1

Comment: you lost $ in the 2nd Lookahead

Comment: @splash58: The "AAAAAAaA " meets the requirements. Reread the question

Comment: @HansGruber: I updated the pattern to just use 1 lookahead with an alternation inside, that should work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.*[A-Z]` will also consume uppers. Use [exclusion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) between upper letters.

```
^(?=.{8})(?:([^A-Z]*[A-Z]){6}.*|(?1)[^A-Z]*$)
```

It checks if there is at least 6 or exactly 1 upper surrounded by non-upper.

- `(?=.{8})` The lookahead at start checks for at least 8 characters
- `(?1)` is a reference to `([^A-Z]*[A-Z])`

More explanation and [demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lS5jH2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think this is not a suitable criteria for strong passwords, but let's cocentrate on the question anyway: count the capital letters in a string.

I think this is really not easy to do using regexp. Does it need to be one? Then you should remove the `php` tag from the question...

PHP solution: I would just filter for the capital letters and count them afterwards.

```
$caps = strlen(preg_replace('/[^A-Z]+/', '', $pass)); // number of uppercase chars in `$pass`

$mediocre = strlen($pass) != 8 || $caps > 5 || $caps < 2;
// mediocre if $pass is not exactly 8 chars long and does not contain between 2 and 5 uppercase characters
```